# Angular Slickgrid column filter not working on formatted column data

Tags: angular, filter, angular-slickgrid, formatted

I am using Angular-Slickgrid 4.1.4, Angular 12
In my data source, I have an array collection of objects. I need to display values from that collection object using a formatter property. But column filter is not working on this formatted column.

```js
this.columnDefinitions = [
  // ......
  { 
    id: 'id', name: 'Customer First Name', field: 'customers', 
    sortable: true, filterable: true, type: FieldType.string,
    formatter: (_row: number, _cell: number, value: any, columnDef: Column<any>, dataContext: any) => {
      return (value != null ) ? value?.firstName: 'NA'},
   },
   // ........
]
```

Need help on column filtering, searched in google but didn't get right solution

Comment: find one solution @ https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Input-Filter#filter-complex-object
Using queryField and formatter properties in ColumnDef. Any other solutions please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Find one solution @ [slickgrid doc](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Input-Filter#filter-complex-object) Using **queryField:** and **formatter:** properties in ColumnDef.

Comment: please note that `queryField` will be used by both Filtering and Sorting, if you don't want that behavior then `queryFieldFilter` might be more suitable for your use case, see all available types in this [Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Input-Filter)